# full screen image with a row of small images below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is an [image slideshow](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html).

My homepage will have such a slideshow. But the top row (sites, files, editor etc) will move to the bottom.

The slide show (with one large image at a time and a  row of small images below) will stretch over the full page.

How can I make it stretch over the full page as i explained before?

**Edit: Actually, what I want to know is how can I make an image (not a background image) stretch over the full page with a little space below?**

Comment: The easiest way would be:

    <html>
    <body>
     <img src="your_img.ext" style="width:100%; height: 90%" />
    </body>
    </html>

But this way you may have problems with keeping the ratio of your image.

Comment: @eymen, another big problem is i have to use a scriprt, so probably can't use a number of images in the way you prescribed..

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .big, .list {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 100px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .list {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        background: #000;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://goo.gl/8JnW8" class="big" alt="" />
<div class="list">{images}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <img id="bgimg" src="image.jpg" alt="Image"/>
</body>
```

You can style it like this:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bgimg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
}
```

This should work.